# Stack Level Too Deep error in test environment only, and only when running rake test:functionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, functional-testing

I am upgrading an app from Rails 3.1 on Ruby 1.9.2 to Rails 3.2 on Ruby 1.9.3. When I step through the app in development everything seems fine. I have no trouble with rake test:units.

But when I run rake test:functionals, I get a "stack level too deep error" in one of my controllers.

Running the test for just that controller, everything's fine:

```
ruby -Itest test/functional/administrators_controller_test.rb
```

and here is the full error text (I have turn installed for slightly prettier output):

```
ERROR (0:00:00.012) comes first
      stack level too deep
    @ /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/layouts.rb:358
```

I'm sure I'm just an idiot, but I haven't the foggiest idea of how to get a stack trace from inside the framework. Running rake test:functionals --trace produces the same error and the same output. I have also changed config.log_level to :debug, and uncommented Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers! in config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb.

I can run other rake tasks, and rake test:units passes all tests.

Anyone have a clue? I could use one.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turned out this was a problem with the functional test of my ActionMailer. In previous versions of Rails I needed to include the URL helpers:

```
# test/functional/notifier_test.rb
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

class NotifierTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  test "test new user email" do
  #...
  end
end
```

When I ran the functional tests one at a time via ruby, I eventually found Notifier was failing with the stack level too deep error; no other test run individually had this problem. But when running rake test:functionals they *all* exhibited the problem.

Commenting out the include line resolved the problem across all functional tests. I'm still not entirely sure why, except that I guess there's some magic callback happening behind the scenes.